# How to map a task's dependencies using Def.app and a KList

Tags: scala, sbt

This question relates to `sbt` 0.13's implementation of KLists as of [this commit](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/8d6dd10798168daa52401db9937daeab8bceefe7). I would like to replicate [this behaviour](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/NRm7nbM3gLY/PvbKmhAHQWEJ), which doesn't work anymore since the KList implementation changed.

The reason why is that currently, sbt only allows up to 11 dependencies if you're grouping them in a tuple. I hear there are performance implications as to why it doesn't allow more, so I'm looking for an alternative to using a tuple and calling `RichTaskables.map` on it, and I'm considering using KLists as this alternative.

*Edit*: Previously I was wondering how to convert a klist into something of type `KL[M[_]]` that `Def.app` and `AList.klist` expects (the latter being required by the former). I then realized that a KList instance can be made into a type constructor of the form `KL[M[_]]` by

- explicitly writing such a type constructor which abstracts over the higher kind, `M` (as Mark Harrah has pointed out in his answer), or
- (I believe) by directly accessing the `kl.Transform` type of the klist `kl` in question.

I've had a go at using `kl.Transform` and it works if all dependencies are all either settings or tasks, but it doesn't directly compile if they are mixed.

Armed with this information, my question remains:

**How can I write some SettingKey & TaskKey dependencies as a KList and use Def.app to map over their values?** I mention `Def.app` for lack of knowing a better, more high-level approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out **one** way to make it work, but I feel like it should be more elegant than that. Going back to the example I want to replicate, the new code having the same behaviour would look like:

```
lazy val yodawg = TaskKey[String]("yo-dawg", "I heard you liked settings, so I put a setting in your setting")

val kl = moduleName :^: version :^: isSnapshot :^: KNil

yodawg <<= Def.app(kl: kl.type#Transform[Def.Initialize]) {
  case a :^: b :^: c :^: KNil => task(List(a, b, c).mkString("~"))
}(AList.klist)
```

But:

- I must explicitly pass in `AList.klist` (maybe expected, it doesn't seem to be defined as an implicit anywhere)
- I must save the klist in a val, and access its `Transform` inner type, which should really be an implementation detail of the klist. In addition, I'm forced to instantiate it too with `Def.Initialize`.

Alternatively I could provide the type in square brackets, but it would look like:

```
Def.app[kl.type#Transform, Task[String]](kl) { ... }
//                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

as in I'd have to provide the inner-type of this setting I'm defining as well.

Comment: Could you approve the answer or **UPDATE** the question to make it more specific (possibly creating other questions if needed)?

Comment: There are still problems with this approach. For one, I can't get it to compile when mixing `TaskKey` and `SettingKey` dependencies. I'll edit the question to remove/explain what was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

`Def.app`, `AList`, and related code are definitely not intended to be used manually.  What is the use case?

To answer the question, the klist-like type constructor you are looking for is:

```
type KSS[M[_]] = KCons[String, KCons[String, KNil, M], M]
```

Like the original KList, it abstracts over the type constructor `M` applied to each element.  In particular, it should not already be applied to a type constructor like `SettingKey` in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to depend on more than 11 settings, which isn't possible using tuples (and I understand that allowing that would make sbt slower to compile), and this KList solution is the only one I've heard being discussed. From what I see, the `KSS` you describe is the same as `myKList.Transform`, which is what I've been trying to use. However, I'm finding this to be problematic when I mix `SettingKey` and `TaskKey` dependencies.

Comment: The standard syntax using `:=` works with an arbitrary number of inputs.  In order to mix `SettingKey/TaskKey` inputs, `SettingKey`s need to be promoted to `Task`s.  The standard syntax does this for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok. I've been trying to avoid that (simply because it breaks highlighting in IntelliJ), but doing this instead is becoming too complex to make it worthwhile. Also, just out of curiosity, is there a similar macro like `.value` to apply to `Def.Initialize` things? (in case I don't want to assign them to a setting, but just use their value directly)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Guess I'll just have to wait for them to finally fix it. (might be a looong wait)

Comment: Ok, make sure to vote if there is a way to do so and if you haven't already.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44684/discussion-between-dan-and-mark-harrah)